# Is there any tools for automatic removal of comments from JavaScript code?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, comments

I'd like to have comments in my code, but I want them to be removed before deploying.
Yes, it's not hard to write such a thing, but if it already exists…
And how about comments in ASP pages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for a JSMin tool or similar.

There are many tools which you can purchase, but there are also some online tools you can use:

http://www.askapache.com/tools/online-compression-tool-compares-packer-jsmin-dojo-and-yui-compressor.html

http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/js-compress/

Good Luck!

Answer (score 7):

[YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) in addition to removing comments and white-spaces, obfuscates local variables using the smallest possible variable name...

Besides the utility, there is the [YUI Compressor Library for .NET](http://www.codeplex.com/YUICompressor), this library allows you to programmatically compress JavaScript and CSS, or use it automatically with MsBuild...

Answer (score 1):

Are you going to compress at runtime? I'd use [packer](http://www.smallsharptools.com/Projects/Packer/) and compress your javascript through a generic handler.